# Apply to_datetime with parameters in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I would like to select columns and apply to_datetime with parameters. I have a working method using lambda but would like to understand why.

Setup

```
d = {'date': ['5/2/2000'], 'date2': ['3/02/2000'], 'date3': ['1-2-2000']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df.dtypes)
```

This works and gives the desired output.

```
df[['date', 'date2', 'date3']] = df[['date', 'date2', 'date3']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, dayfirst=True))

output
    date        date2       date3
0   2000-02-05  2000-02-03  2000-02-01
```

This works but does not take parameters so does not work with UK dates.

```
df[['date', 'date2', 'date3']] = df[['date', 'date2', 'date3']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

output (incorrect)
    date        date2       date3
0   2000-05-02  2000-03-02  2000-01-02
```

This does not work but why?

```
df[['date', 'date2', 'date3']] = df[['date', 'date2', 'date3']].apply(pd.to_datetime(dayfirst=True))

error

TypeError: to_datetime() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'
```

Why can I not apply to_datetime with parameters? Is this always the case with apply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `dayfirst=True` as a parameter to [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) (look at the **`**kwargs`** parameter):

```py
df[["date", "date2", "date3"]] = df[["date", "date2", "date3"]].apply(
    pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        date      date2      date3
0 2000-02-05 2000-02-03 2000-02-01
```

Comment: Yes I see now. As you say **kwargs allows additional keyword arguments to pass as keywords arguments to func.